# Show FormCraft form on page open

Tags: pages

I am using WordPress FormCraft plugin on my site. I created a form and got the form short embedded code

```
[fc id='4'][/fc]
```

I want to show this form when the user opens the page.

Can anyone tell how can approach this?

I also try in Page Editor I got an option to add form
it generated below code for me.

```
[fc id='4' type='popup' button_color='#4488ee' font_color='white'][/fc]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://formcraft-wp.com/help/how-to-use-a-custom-popup-form-trigger/),  you have to use the shortcode:

```
[fc id='12' type='popup'][/fc]
```

Next, something has to trigger the form, you can create a button for that and then click it from jQury, edit the link which would trigger this form, and put the href or hyperlink to:

```
<a class="triggerForm" href="http://yoursite.com/form-view/12">Link Trigger</a>
```

jQuery trigger.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('a.triggerForm').click();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a simple solution without changing any code. I have used another plugin [Popup maker](https://wordpress.org/plugins/popup-maker/) that will create a pop-up, there I can configure on page load / with time delay.